# Python Logging using queueListeners and queueHandlers along with file config

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I already have a custom python logging script which I import in other modules to create logger instances for each module. I am using a .ini config file and loading using config.fileConfig(). Now, for optimization, I want to use the queueHandlers and queueListeners method to create a non-blocking call for loggers.

I found the following example in python documentations and found it useful:

```
que = queue.Queue(-1)  # no limit on size
queue_handler = QueueHandler(que)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
listener = QueueListener(que, handler)
root = logging.getLogger()
root.addHandler(queue_handler)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(threadName)s: %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
listener.start()
# The log output will display the thread which generated
# the event (the main thread) rather than the internal
# thread which monitors the internal queue. This is what
# you want to happen.
root.warning('Look out!')
listener.stop()
```

However, I am not sure how can I re-implement the above piece of code using .ini config file? Can someone please guide me with this.

My config file looks something like this:
`logging.ini` :

```
[loggers]
keys=root,rcs_logger

[handlers]
keys=console,file

[formatters]
keys=file,console

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console

[logger_rcs_logger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=file,console
qualname=rcs_logger
propagate=0

[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=console
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_file]
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=file
args=('%(logfilename)s', 's', 5, 0, 'utf8')

[formatter_file]
format={"observed_timestamp": %(observedTime)d, "observed_timestamp_rfc3339": "%(observedTimeRfc3339)s", "intrumentation_scope": "%(filename)s", "hostname": "%(hostname)s", "severity_text": "%(levelname)s","severity_number": %(levelno)s, "event_timestamp": %(eventTime)s, "body": "%(message)s", "resource": "%(node)s",  "span_id": "%(spanId)s", "trace_id": "%(traceId)s"}
datefmt=%s

[formatter_console]
format=[%(levelname)s][%(levelno)s] %(message)s
datefmt=
```

How do I implement the same using queueHandlers and queueListeners?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### `logging.ini` file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,rcs_logger

[handlers]
keys=console,file,queue

[formatters]
keys=file,console

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=console,queue

[logger_rcs_logger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=file,console,queue
qualname=rcs_logger
propagate=0

[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=console
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_file]
class=logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=file
args=('%(logfilename)s', 's', 5, 0, 'utf8')

[handler_queue]
class=queue.QueueHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=file
args=(queue.Queue(-1),)

[formatter_file]
format={"observed_timestamp": %(observedTime)d, "observed_timestamp_rfc3339": "%(observedTimeRfc3339)s", "intrumentation_scope": "%(filename)s", "hostname": "%(hostname)s", "severity_text": "%(levelname)s","severity_number": %(levelno)s, "event_timestamp": %(eventTime)s, "body": "%(message)s", "resource": "%(node)s",  "span_id": "%(spanId)s", "trace_id": "%(traceId)s"}
datefmt=%s

[formatter_console]
format=[%(levelname)s][%(levelno)s] %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Now, simply create a `QueueListener` instance and add it to the logger's handlers:

#### `main.py` file:

```py
import logging
import queue

que = queue.Queue(-1)
queue_handler = logging.handlers.QueueHandler(que)

listener = logging.handlers.QueueListener(que, *logging.getLogger().handlers)
listener.start()

# Now you can log messages using the logger as usual
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("This is a tayst message")

listener.stop()
```